# Inner class always empty when retrieving data using ORMLite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite in my Android application, and I'm trying to persist and query a nested class. Creation and updating models is error-free, though I don't know if it's persisting the models how I'd expect. When I query for the model, I get the outer class's data fine, but it never gets the inner class data. Here's my model (stripped down for readability):

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Race {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String raceId;
    @DatabaseField
    private String name;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private Collection<Rule> rules;

    @DatabaseTable
    public static class Rule {

        @DatabaseField
        private long ruleId;
        @DatabaseField
        private String name;
        @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
        private Race race;
    }
}
```

My add method:

```
public boolean addOrUpdateRace(Race race) {

    CreateOrUpdateStatus status = mHelper.getRaceDao().createOrUpdate(race);
    return status.isCreated() || status.isUpdated();
}
```

My query method:

```
public List<Race> getAllRaces() {

    return mHelper.getRaceDao().queryForAll();
}
```

The list from `getAllRaces` has all the expected variables populated (raceId and name) and has a `ForeignCollection` for `rules`. When I attempt to access `rules`, I get an iterator that has a size of 0.

I wasn't sure about what to do with the `Race` variaible in the `Rule` class, I just knew ORMLite threw errors when I didn't include it. I've tried leaving it null in the hopes that ORMLite would automagically make the connection with its parent, and when that didn't work I tried setting the `race` variable just before persisting, but that had the same effect.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Can you post your query and result map for getForAll?

Comment: @ThrashBean The query method is the last method I posted. What do you mean by "result map"? The list that's returned from querying?

Comment: Yes, what you return from the query. I think you define it in yor xml.

Comment: @ThrashBean I haven't had to define anything in XML for ORMLite. All the data I get back from querying is defined in the model class (variables annotated with `@DatabaseField` and `@ForeignCollectionField`). From debugging, I get a list of all the races I added to the database with a `ForeignCollection` object for `rules`. However, the iterator in `rules' has a size of 0, even though each races has 1 or 2 rules each when I add them to the database.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've never worked with ORMLite. For me looks like Rule doesn't know about Race. At [THIS LINK](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#Foreign-Collection) I see something about eager and it's default value is **false**. May be you can try putting it to **true** to avoid lazy loading. Realy don't know.

Comment: @ThrashBean I've tried that before and had the same issue. It should work regardless if it's eager or lazy. That just determines if it's front loaded or loaded when accessed. I think the problem is that I need to populate the Rule table when I populate the Race table (I assumed this would happen automagically with the library, but that may not be the case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DB/Table for Rule doesn't appear to be being populated based on the code you provided.

You need to create a Dao for the 'Rule' class and have an appropriate addOrUpdateRule(Rule rule) used during parsing since ORMLite cannot automagically populate the DB/Table for Rule based on its association as a ForeignCollectionField within the 'Race' class.